# GCloud bug: I have configured my DNS dinhonesto.com.br and www.dinhonesto.com.br of type A to an external ip but only dinhonesto.com.br is working

Tags: dns, subdomain, gcloud

I have configured my DNS dinhonesto.com.br and `www.dinhonesto.com.br` of type A to an external ip but only `dinhonesto.com.br` is working.

NOTE: it is not working since 15 days ago

```
DNS Name                 Type   TTL (secs)   Data
www.dinhonesto.com.br.   A      300          34.98.110.250 
dinhonesto.com.br.       A      300          34.98.110.250
```

When I try to ping both domains (dinhonesto.com.br and [www.dinhonesto.com.br](http://www.dinhonesto.com.br))

```
$ ping -c 3 dinhonesto.com.br
PING dinhonesto.com.br (34.98.110.250) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 250.110.98.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.98.110.250): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=11.6 ms
64 bytes from 250.110.98.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.98.110.250): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=11.6 ms
64 bytes from 250.110.98.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.98.110.250): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=11.5 ms

--- dinhonesto.com.br ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 4884ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.557/11.636/11.686/0.136 ms
$ ping -c 3 www.dinhonesto.com.br
ping: www.dinhonesto.com.br: Name or service not known
```

When I `ping` `www.dinhonesto.com.br` I get `Name or service not known`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution just today, I have created an A record pointing to the External IP of my google cloud instance because I was having an error when creating a CNAME `"Managed zone may have either one CNAME resource record set or resource record sets of other types, but not both."`
. I have just changed my `DS record` from `www.dinhonesto.com.br` to `ds.dinhonesto.com.br` and it now is working fine! I even managed to use CNAME to point `www.dinhonesto.com.br` to `dinhonesto.com.br` and it is working fine too!
I hope this help somebody, Google Cloud should give an error message when we try to create an `A record` that conflicts with a `DS record`.
I have also tested both `www.dinhonesto.com.br` and `dinhonesto.com.br` with [dnssec-analyzer](https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/) and everything is fine.